# Exclude posts in home slider from sections

Tags: posts, wp-query, tags

I have home page with a main slider and news section.

- Main slider
- Sport section news
- Economy section news
- Politic section news
- and others section

The main slider get posts by tag ='slider', and display 10 posts limit.

The sections get posts by category (each section by specific category)

What i wold like is to : exclude the posts displaying in slider, from the sections until the posts is out the slider.

Here is the code of the slider and a sample of section:

**Slider Code :**

```
<?php
// Slider
$tag = ap_option('slider_tag');
$count = ap_option('slider_count');
$slid = new WP_Query(
array(
'tag'            => $tag ,
'posts_per_page' => $count ,
'post__not_in'   => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
)
);
?>
<div class="thumbslider">
<div class="postlist">
<?php while ( $slid->have_posts() ) : $slid->the_post(); ?>
<div class="item">
<div class="det">
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"><?php 
the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>">
            <?php 
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
              the_post_thumbnail( 'slider' );
            } else {
              echo '<img alt="Assahifa.com" title="Assahifa.com" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&bg=eee&txtclr=8C8C8C%26text%3Dthree&txt=ap&w=650&h=420">';
            } 
            ?>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php endwhile;wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**Section News Sample :**

```
   <?php
   // cat eco
   $n=0;
   $cat_eco = ap_option('sec_eco_cat');
   $count_eco = ap_option('sec_eco_count');
   $eco = new WP_Query(
   array(
   'cat'            => $cat_eco ,
   'posts_per_page' => $count_eco ,
   'post__not_in'   => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
   'offset'         => 0,
     )
   );
   ?>
   <section class="main_eco clearfix">
   <div class="box">
   <div class="title" style="color: <?php echo ap_option('eco-color'); ?>;"> 
   <h3 style="color: <?php echo ap_option('eco-color'); ?>;"><a href="<?php  
   echo get_category_link( $cat_eco ); ?>" title="<?php echo 
   ap_option('sec_eco_title'); ?>" style="color: <?php echo ap_option('eco- 
   color'); ?>;"><?php echo ap_option('sec_eco_title'); ?></a></h3></div>
   <div class="postlist">
      <?php while ( $eco->have_posts() ) : $eco->the_post();$n++; ?>
      <div class="item clearfix">
        <div class="thumbnail imgtrans">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>">
            <?php 
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
              the_post_thumbnail( 'md' );
            } else {
              echo '<img alt="AisPanel" title="AisPanel" 
      src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text? 
      txtsize=20&bg=eee&txtclr=8C8C8C%26text%3Dthree&txt=ap&w=650&h=420">';
            } 
            ?>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="det">
          <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title();? 
       >"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
          <!--<?php if($n == 1) the_excerpt(); ?>-->
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php endwhile;wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: All codes are written in one single PHP file?

Comment: If all loops are written in same file, then you can apply do_not_duplicate idea here.

Comment: No , each code is separated: main-slider.php & section-eco.php

Comment: How are you getting `$slid_post` variable in news section file? are you using the get_template_part() function in main PHP file (home.php/index.php)

Comment: Oops i just remember! in the origin it's was 'get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),'-- that was me trying some solution, i just edit the code again

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are saving the slider code in **slider.php** file, news section code in **section-news.php** file and following this kind of snippets in front-page/home/index .php file

```
get_template_part('slider');
get_templates_part('section-news');
```

then you can edit the slider.php file and add the new array variable **$do_not_duplicate**. So it is preserving the slider post IDs for future use. Here is the new code for slider

```
<?php
// Slider
$tag = ap_option('slider_tag');
$count = ap_option('slider_count');
$do_not_duplicate = array();
$slid = new WP_Query(
  array(
  'tag'            => $tag ,
  'posts_per_page' => $count ,
  'post__not_in'   => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
  )
);
?>
<div class="thumbslider">
  <div class="postlist">
    <?php 
      while ( $slid->have_posts() ) : 
        $slid->the_post(); 
        $do_not_duplicate[] = get_the_ID();
    ?>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="det">
          <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>">
              <?php 
              if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                the_post_thumbnail( 'slider' );
              } else {
                echo '<img alt="Assahifa.com" title="Assahifa.com" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&bg=eee&txtclr=8C8C8C%26text%3Dthree&txt=ap&w=650&h=420">';
              } 
              ?>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      <?php endwhile;wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I shall exclude the slider post from news loop. Here is the new code for news section. Merging **$do_not_duplicate** array with `get_option( 'sticky_posts' )` value and passing into **post__not_in** array key.

```
<?php
   // cat eco
   $n=0;
   $cat_eco = ap_option('sec_eco_cat');
   $count_eco = ap_option('sec_eco_count');
   $sticky_posts = ( get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) ) ? get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) : array();
   $eco = new WP_Query(
     array(
       'cat'            => $cat_eco ,
       'posts_per_page' => $count_eco ,
       'post__not_in'   => array_merge( $do_not_duplicate, $sticky_posts ),
       'offset'         => 0,
      )
   );
   ?>
   <section class="main_eco clearfix">
   <div class="box">
   <div class="title" style="color: <?php echo ap_option('eco-color'); ?>;"> 
   <h3 style="color: <?php echo ap_option('eco-color'); ?>;"><a href="<?php  
   echo get_category_link( $cat_eco ); ?>" title="<?php echo 
   ap_option('sec_eco_title'); ?>" style="color: <?php echo ap_option('eco- 
   color'); ?>;"><?php echo ap_option('sec_eco_title'); ?></a></h3></div>
   <div class="postlist">
      <?php while ( $eco->have_posts() ) : $eco->the_post();$n++; ?>
      <div class="item clearfix">
        <div class="thumbnail imgtrans">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>">
            <?php 
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
              the_post_thumbnail( 'md' );
            } else {
              echo '<img alt="AisPanel" title="AisPanel" 
      src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text? 
      txtsize=20&bg=eee&txtclr=8C8C8C%26text%3Dthree&txt=ap&w=650&h=420">';
            } 
            ?>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="det">
          <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title();? 
       >"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
          <!--<?php if($n == 1) the_excerpt(); ?>-->
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php endwhile;wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: i try to add 'get_template_part' but it's duplicate the section and slider in home page, it's well be great if there is a solution just between the slider and the sections. tnx for your help and excuse my English

Comment: yesterday i find a code that maybe can help at : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/121428/158072

Comment: I edited my answer. You will not add get_template_part. You already included the slider and news code in your theme file.

Comment: Hello again - i tried all the code above but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

With a friend we find a solution : 
- we create a exclude function in functions.php
- then we call it where we went

This the code for functions.php

```
    // Function exlude
        if( !function_exists('get_slide_ids') ){
        function get_slide_ids() {  
        global $wp_query;
        $POST_LIMIT = ap_option('slider_count');
        $POST_TAG = ap_option('slider_tag');
        $ids= [];
        $args =  array(
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'tag'            => $POST_TAG ,
                    'posts_per_page' => $POST_LIMIT ,
                );
        $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if ($wp_query->have_posts() ):
            while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
                  $ids[] = get_the_ID(); 
            endwhile;   
            return $ids;
        endif; 
        return '';
        }
     }
```

To call it add the syntaxe not in, this my code just try a adopt it to yours :

```
     <?php
      /**
      // cat eco
      $n=0;
      $cat_eco = ap_option('sec_eco_cat');
      $count_eco = ap_option('sec_eco_count');
      $sticky_posts = ( get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) ) ? get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) : array();
      $eco = new WP_Query(
      array(
        'cat'            => $cat_eco ,
        'posts_per_page' => $count_eco ,
        'post__not_in'   => get_slide_ids(),
           )
         );
       ?>
```